# Declaring arrays inside an if statement

Tags: c, arrays, if-statement

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char x;

    printf("enter something ");
    scanf("%c",&x);

    if(x == 's') char y[] = "sauve";

    else char y[] = "hi"

    printf("%s",y);
    getch();
}
```

It says "y" is not declared first. I'm new to arrays. What I want to do is display the string "suave" when the user inputs letter s.

Comment: you could have got the reason if you had used curly braces with `if else` that makes things clear that there is no scope of `y` after `if else block`

Comment: @CarlNorum I never mentioned that OP's code has syntax error - other than that mising semicolon in else

Comment: @sansix - yes you did - you said `y` wasn't in scope at the `printf`.  But that's not the OP's problem.  The OP's problem is that you can't make variable declarations in an `if` statement expression (unless you add some braces to make a compound statement).

Comment: @CarlNorum you may have 89k worth of rep, but i think you got the wrong end of the stick on this question.

Comment: @CarlNorum oopps my bad - missed that declaration part - appologies

Comment: I don't know, there's a perfectly correct answer with 4 upvotes; I'm not really sure why people feel compelled to add wrong and/or misleading answers on top of that.

Answer (score 4):

Do like:

```
 char *y;
 if(x == 's') y = "sauve";
 else y = "hi";
 printf("%s",y);
```

Otherwise you have to use `strcpy()` and declare array before if:

```
 char y[SIZE] = "";       //1. sufficiently long size
 if(x == 's') 
      strcpy(y, "sauve"); //2. after declaration you can't assign used strcpy
 else 
     strcpy(y, "hi");
 printf("%s", y);        //3. now scope is not problem
```

Comment: +1, although in all practical situation, I'd use a `char const*` even though the C standard doesn't require that.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan - good idea; that will match the intended semantics better.

Answer (score 2):

You code translates to

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
    char x;
    printf("enter something ");
    scanf("%c",&x);
    if(x == 's') {
        char y[] = "sauve";
    } else {
        char y[] = "hi";
    }
    printf("%s",y);
    getch();
}
```

As might seem more obvious now, the variable 'y' that you declare is bound to the { ... } scopes it is declared in.  You cannot use 'y' outside of the scope it was declared in.  To fix this, declare 'y' in the outer scope like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
    char x;
    printf("enter something ");
    scanf("%c",&x);
    const char *y;
    if(x == 's') {
        y = "sauve";
    } else {
        y = "hi";
    }
    printf("%s",y);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Note also how I use a pointer instead of an array, because the size of the array can't be known when 'y' is defined.  Also don't forget to return something from main().

Comment: Your first example doesn't match OP's case; adding the braces makes the program have different semantics (and a different syntax error).

Answer (score 2):

Use this instead :

```
char *y;
if(x == 's') y = "sauve";
else y = "hi";

printf("%s",y);
```

By declaring `y` before the `if` statement and not inside, you are extending the `y` scope. And you don't need braces here.

---

**EDIT :** (From the comment of Eric and Carl)

```
if (x == 's') char y[] = "sauve";
else char y[] = "hi";

printf("%s",y);
```

> In the C grammar, a **declaration** is not a statement. The syntax for `if` is `if (expression) statement [else statement]`. The single “statement” in an if without braces must be a statement. It may not be a **declaration**. It can be a *compound-statement*, which is a *brace-enclosed block-item-list*, and *block-item-list* may be or contain a **declaration**.

So here the declaration is purely illegal. You cannot declare `y` in an `if-statement` without braces.

But if you add braces :

```
if (x == 's') { char y[] = "sauve"; }
else { char y[] = "hi"; }

printf("%s",y);
```

Here it is legal in theory but there is a new problem now... The declaration of `y` is now bounded to the `{ ... }` scope. There will be an error of the type : `error: use of undeclared identifier 'y'` on the `printf` line.

Comment: There is no block scoped `y` in the OP's example.

Comment: @CarlNorum Please check again. The `{}` are just optional here. But in the OP's example, `y` is scoped inside the `if` statement ...... I don't think the -1 is justified here...

Comment: @CarlNorum isn't it the fact that when we don't write braces explicitly - it only includes the next single line of statement

Comment: @PierreFourgeaud: In the C grammar, a `declaration` is not a `statement`. The syntax for `if` is `if (expression) statement [else statement]`. The single “statement” in an `if` without braces must be a `statement`. It may not be a `declaration`. It can be a `compound-statement`, which is a brace-enclosed `block-item-list`, and `block-item-list` may be or contain a `declaration`.

Comment: +1 @Eric; the declaration is just not allowed at *all*.  Adding the braces changes the error from `error: expected expression` or something like that to `error: use of undeclared identifier 'y'`.

Comment: @sansix - no, it's not.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thank you for pointing this out. I edited my post with your suggestion/comment. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Your array declaration is in if scope not in the main function. Therefore you can't acces them. Declare it at the beginning of the main function. it is nothing special to arrays. Technically in C89, all the variables are defined at the starting of a scope, C++ allows the declaration of variable anywhere in the scope. (Thanks to the larsmans for his comments. I think many textbooks and blog entries should be updated.)

Comment: There is no block in the OP's `if` statement.

Comment: Only in C89 do you need to declare variables at the start of a scope. C99 relaxed this requirement and the current standard is C11.

Answer (score -1):

If I put in the `blocks {}` we get:

```
#include<stdio.h>
    int main(){
    char x;

    printf("enter something ");
    scanf("%c",&x);

    if(x == 's') { char y[] = "sauve";}

    else {char y[] = "hi";}

    printf("%s",y); /* y is now out of scope of both its declarations*/
    getch();
   }
```

Does that explain what is happening ?

Comment: Adding the blocks isn't relevant to the OP's case; he has a syntax error, not a scoping error.

Comment: @CarlNorum - Actually As the op said he was a newb, i was trying to clarify for him what was happening _BECAUSE_ of scoping. If you had bothered to compile my code you will see that it does complain that y is out of scope, and IMHO this is exactly what the op was struggling with.